# How to extract data from ng-multiselect-dropdown list in number format instead of Array

Tags: angular

I need to send object through post from angular UI to REST API.
In Angular UI,I am capturing dealid from multiselect dropdown using **ng-multiselect-dropdown** component.
and my deal object of class DealApi looks like this:

```
export class DealApi{
        applicationReceived: any;
        dealid: number;
        expectedReleaseDate: Date;
        plannedRatingCommitteeDate: Date;
        priority: any;
        releaseTimeCriteria: any;
        subsequentRating: any;

}
```

in app.component.html:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown name="dropdown"
             [placeholder]="'Enter Deal Name or Deal ID'"
             [settings]="dropdownSettings"
             [data]="dropdownList" 
             [(ngModel)]="deal.dealid"
              (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
              (onDeSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
              (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
              (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" disabled>
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
          </td>
```

And in app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-app';
  name = 'angular-app';
  datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems: any;
  dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings;
  dealid : number;
  PlannedRatingCommitteeDate: Date;
  ExpectedReleaseDate: Date;
  ReleaseTimeCriteria: any;
  SubsequentRating: any;
  Priority: any;
  ApplicationReceived: any;
  deal:DealApi= new DealApi();
  constructor(private service:HttpclientService) {}
  ngOnInit(){
  this.dropdownList = [
    {item_id:1, item_text: "Dealname1 (82034890)"},
    {item_id:2, item_text: "Dealname2 (82034890)"},
    {item_id:3, item_text: "Dealname3 (82034890)"},
    {item_id:4, item_text: "Dealname4 (82034890)"}
  ];
  this.selectedItems = [
    {item_id: 2, item_text: "Dealname1 (82034890)"},
      {item_id: 3, item_text: "Dealname2 (82034890)"}
  ];
   this.dropdownSettings = {
     singleSelection: true,
     enableCheckAll:true,
     idField: 'item_id',
     textField: 'item_text',
     selectAllText: 'Select All',
     unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
     itemsShowLimit: 3,
     allowSearchFilter: true
   };
```

and On Angular UI, When I click save button it calls save() method which calls getdeals(this.deal) like below:

```
this.service.getdeals(this.deal).subscribe((data:any)=>{alert("Deal added successfully.");});
```

and in httpClient.service.ts,I am calling post while passing deal object:

```
public getdeals(deal: DealApi)
  {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      })
    };
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/deals';
  console.log(deal);
     return this.http.post(url,deal,httpOptions);
}
```

IN OUTPUT: 
I am getting deal object as:

```
{
dealid: [{item_id: 3, item_text: "Dealname3 (82034890)"}]
plannedRatingCommitteeDate: "2020-04-05T04:00:00.000Z"
expectedReleaseDate: "2020-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"
releaseTimeCriteria: "Market open"
subsequentRating: "No"
priority: "High"
applicationReceived: "No"
}
```

and it is throwing error:
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `int` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `int` out of START_ARRAY token↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream)

I need only item_id to be assigned to dealid and dealid should come as number instead of array.
How can I modify my code for this?

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one parameter in component.ts such as

```
selected:any;
```

then in html change model to this

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown name="dropdown"
             [placeholder]="'Enter Deal Name or Deal ID'"
             [settings]="dropdownSettings"
             [data]="dropdownList" 
             [(ngModel)]="selected"
              (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
              (onDeSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
              (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
              (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" disabled>
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
          </td>
```

then in `onItemSelect($event)` function assign your id

```
onItemSelect(event){
  if(this.selected.length>0){
    this.deal.dealid=this.selected[0].id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I know what are you assigning to selected parameter clearly?

Comment: selected is for output of ng-multiselect-dropdown element. This element always give object as output but in event methods u can assign this output to your model

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selected"
[settings]="dropdownSettings"
[data]="dropdownList"
>
<div *ngFor="let item of selected">
<p>{{item.item_text}}</p>
</div>
```

`above div is the confirmation that the code is properly working.If you are able to see that the items are  being displayed on screen as you keep selecting or deselecting the options , means the code is working well. Later on you can remove the div .`
`In your component.ts file write below code`

```
selected:any; 
dropdownList:any = [];
dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings={};
ngOnInit() {
this.dropdownList = [
{ item_id: 1, item_text: 'Item1' },
{ item_id: 2, item_text: 'Item2' },
{ item_id: 3, item_text: 'Item3' },
{ item_id: 4, item_text: 'Item4' },
{ item_id: 5, item_text: 'Item5' }
];
this.dropdownSettings = {
idField: 'item_id',
textField: 'item_text',
};
}
```